# I need to loop through a set of images and show them one after the other from react native

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

I am new to **React native.** 
I have a set of images (1.png, 2.png, 3.png .... 20.png). I want to show these images from one after the other in a loop, so it will look like a **video** at the front end. I have tried some coding but failed. Can some body help me with this.

I wanted to create something like this:

```
class BasicStructure extends Component{

render(){
  return()=>{
      for (let i = 1; i < 20; i++) {
        <Image source={require(`./assets/imageLoop/${i}.png`)}>
        </Image>
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But this is not working.

Comment: `for loop` should be used before the return

Comment: @RakeshKumar I have tried that. but it does not help.

Comment: Is your path correct?

Comment: @RakeshKumar Yes. when it is single image it works.

Comment: Check this link may it helps you https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-image-sequence

Comment: @KaushikRadadiya your answer pointed to a working solution. there are things to be improved but the solution in the url works. **Thank You**. Can you please add this as an answer to the question so others also will easily get this solution.

Comment: I have added it. Can you please accept my solution so others will get this easily. **Thank you**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow the below link If you want to use multiple images in a single view.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-image-sequence

This may help you.

Answer (score 4):

React Native does not allow dynamic paths to static image resources. See https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/images#static-image-resources

So you will need to `require` all of your images first.

Secondly you must return a single jsx element or a fragment from your render function, so if you want several image tags, wrap them in a `<> </>` fragment.

something like:

```
const images = [
  require('./assets/imageLoop/1.png'),
  require('./assets/imageLoop/2.png'),
  ...
  require('./assets/imageLoop/19.png'),
];
class BasicStructure extends Component{

  render(){
    return (
     <>
       {images.map(img => <Image source={img} />)}
     </>
    );
  }
}
```

This should get you close to your original code, but will not animate the images like a video. I would suggest opening another question for that if this solves the problem of at least rendering all of the images.

Comment: Yes you are correct this does not animate but with this solves the problem of rendering. So I need to find a way to show only one image at a time. **Thank You**